# Can i have a function inside a state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create variables and a function inside a state like this

```
     state = {
          modalVisible: false,
          photo:""
          getDataSourceState
    }
```

which i have done, how can i call the function outside the state and set a new state.

This what i have done but i keep getting errors

```
    getDataSourceState() {
        return {
          dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.images),
        };
      }



    this.setState(this.getDataSourceState());
```

see what prompted me to ask the question, because i was finding it difficult to access modalVisible in the state since there is a this.state = this.getDataSource()

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalVisible: false,
      photo:"",
      sourceState: getDataSourceState()
    }
    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.lastPhotoFetched = undefined;
    this.images = [];
    this.fetchPhotos();
    this.getDataSourceState = this.getDataSourceState.bind(this)
  }

componentDidMount(){
  this.getDataSourceState();
}

  getDataSourceState() {
    return {
      dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.images),
    };
  }

  getPhotosFromCameraRollData(data) {
    return data.edges.map((asset) => {
      return asset.node.image;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want a function in the state? It would be much better to have it as a component method.

Comment: so that i can update the function each time there is an update

Comment: Not sure if you can but I can't imagine why would you want that. A state is local to the component so why not just call the function defined inside it. @D.Moplio What do you want to update from the function?

Comment: am using a listvew from react component to hold images from gallery @Rodius

Comment: Please go through react life-cycle methods(https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Comment: There is no reason to have a function inside a state. You can set it to your class and call it with an argument

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't the way you have attempted but technically yes, you can have a function that returns the desired state you want initialised in your constructor. I wouldn't suggest doing it though.

You will quickly run into issues where your components aren't updating state correctly.

What you are looking for is a function that returns a value as opposed to sets state. You would do something like this:

```
constructor(){
  super()

  this.state = {
    modalVisible: false,
    photo:""
    sourceState: this.getDataSourceState()
  }

  this.getDataSourceState = this.getDataSourceState.bind(this)
}

getDataSourceState(){
  return this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.images)
}
```

As I mentioned, it is not a good idea to do it this way. You are better off initialising the state values as a default value and then setting the state in your componentDidMount like so:

```
constructor(){
    super()

    this.state = {
        modalVisible: false,
        photo:""
        sourceState: null
    }

    this.getDataSourceState = this.getDataSourceState.bind(this)
}


componentDidMount(){
    this.getDataSourceState()
}

getDataSourceState(){

    const data = this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.images)

    this.setState({soureState: data})
    
}
```

This way you have a reusable function which you can call in `componentDidUpdate()` if need be for when you move navigate between the same component with different data and want the state to update.

Comment: the first example should have something like getDataSourceState.bind(this)

Comment: @Stretch0  see what prompted me to inside getDataSourceState() inside the state.                                                             
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    state = {
      modalVisible: false,
      photo:"",
    }
    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.lastPhotoFetched = undefined;
    this.images = [];
    this.state = this.getDataSourceState();
    this.fetchPhotos();
  
  }

Comment: @D.Moplio I'm not sure what you're trying to say there. Might help to move the code into your original post as and edit

Comment: @Stretch0 just did that

Comment: @D.Moplio I'm still confused what you are trying to do. You are trying to set state in your constructor with `state = {}`. You need to use `this.state = {}`. You are overriding your state when you call `this.state = this.getDataSourceState();`. Very confussing

Comment: am sorry about that @Stretch0, that what what prompted me to ask the question. thats why i brought the function into the state from my very first question

Comment: @Moplio I think that was a typo having the `getDataSourceState` called within constructor. I have now removed it and initialised the value as `null` but it may be better suited to another value

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

```
class App extends Component {
    func1 = () => {
        this.setState({flag:!this.state.flag})
    }
   state = {
       flag:true,       
       doclick:this.func1
    }
}
```