# Pass function in component constructor in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

A questions about this snake game i'm developing with react.

I read on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510990/can-i-have-a-function-inside-a-state-in-react) about setting function inside the constructor. Now for the example, I want snakeMoves function to call foodGenerator, which is in the constructor, but not in the state, so call this.state inside snakeMoves won't get me foodGenerator.

what options do I have to pass foodGenerator to snakeMoves?

```
 class Play extends Component {
            constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state ={
                gameSqueres: [],
                food: null
            }

            this.foodGenerator = this.foodGenerator.bind(this)
        }

    componentDidMount() {
            // create food
            this.foodGenerator()
        }

    foodGenerator() {
        console.log('food')
    }

    // snake move system
    snakeMoves = (e) => {
        const { gameSqueres } = this.state;
        console.log(foodGenerator())
    }
```

Comment: There is no need of the line `this.foodGenerator = this.foodGenerator.bind(this)`. Simply make `foodGenerator` as an Arrow Function and refer it using `this.foodGenerator()`

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is just to bind `this` and get a new function, you can use arrow functions instead. From the method `snakeMoves()`, simply call: `this.foodGenerator()`

```
foodGenerator = () => {
    console.log('food')
}
```

Comment: Ok I see now that it's working, but how do I avoid the returning of "undefined" aside to the foodGenerator execution?

Comment: @Bizzaros: AFIK javascript will always return something on a statement execution, if a particular statenent doesn't return anything, ut would return `undefined`. Under `snakeMoves()` there is no need to do a `console.log(this.foodGenerator())`, simply do, `this.foodGenerator()`. Or, if you want to do a console log in snakeMoves, then return a value from `foodGenerator` instead of logging it there

Answer (score 0):

Use **this** to access class methods.

```
snakeMoves = (e) => {
    const { gameSqueres } = this.state;
    console.log(this.foodGenerator())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just do this:

```
// snake move system
snakeMoves = (e) => {
   this.foodGenerator();
}
```