# How a function can be called inside a function having setState inside it without component mount, in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use a function inside a bind function, using the answer given in [Can i have a function inside a state in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510990/can-i-have-a-function-inside-a-state-in-react). I also tried to use JSON.stringify the 'const data'. I can print buttons, but I am trying to store the clicked buttons in value.

```
const InitArr = ({ myArray, handleClick }) => ( <div> {myArray.map(item => (<button onClick={() => handleClick(item.key)}>{item.key}</button> ))}    </div>)
class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {myArray: [{"key": "7"},{"key": "8"},{"key": "9"},{"key": "4"},{"key": "5"},{"key": "6"},{"key": "1"},{"key": "2"},{"key": "3"},{"key": "0"}], value: '0', };
     this.setValues = this.setValues.bind(this)
     this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
   }
   setValues(key) {
      const temp = key
   }
   handleClick(key) {
       const { value } = this.state
       const data = setValues(key)
       this.setState({ value: data })
    }
    render() {
    return (
       <div>
          <div>{this.state.value}</div>
              <InitArr myArray={this.state.myArray} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
       </div>
     );}}
     ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: What behavior are you expecting when a click occurs?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is the purpose and/or point of `setValues`? It returns undefined. Can you provide a little more context?

Comment: Trying to print the buttons and after click store in value.

Comment: The buttons will continue to be printed if you simply leave off the `setState`...?

Comment: also store them in a string in value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you were calling `setValues(key)` rather than `this.setValues(key)`, so it couldn't find `setValues` in the current scope.

Changing that allows the code to run, though I also changed setValue to return something so the rendered number will not just dissapear:

```
setValues(key) {
    const temp = key;
    return key;
  }
```

```js
const InitArr = ({ myArray, handleClick }) => (
  <div>
    {' '}
    {myArray.map((item) => (
      <button onClick={() => handleClick(item.key)}>{item.key}</button>
    ))}{' '}
  </div>
);
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myArray: [
        { key: '7' },
        { key: '8' },
        { key: '9' },
        { key: '4' },
        { key: '5' },
        { key: '6' },
        { key: '1' },
        { key: '2' },
        { key: '3' },
        { key: '0' },
      ],
      value: '0',
    };
    this.setValues = this.setValues.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  setValues(key) {
    const temp = key;
    return key;
  }
  handleClick(key) {
    const { value } = this.state;
    console.log(key);
    const data = this.setValues(key);
    this.setState({ value: data });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.value}</div>
        <InitArr myArray={this.state.myArray} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: I still don't think there's enough context and information to accurately answer the question. The OP hasn't even clearly stated what the issue is. For this solution you may as well just `this.setState({ value: key });` and skip the `setValues` function that doesn't do anything. Well, I guess it resolves something for the OP.